# How to derive the Vandermonde Determinant?

Tags: numerical-methods, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations

[image]I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87iJTcXqTKY explaning the Vandermonde Determinant I understood everything but I was wondering why the guy never mentioned the (-1)^(i+j) term used in solving determinants?

Comment: wasn't the method used in the video cofactor expansion? I still don't understand why the (-1)^(i+j) term wasn't mentioned please explain it to me sir

Comment: The $(-1)^{i+j}$ is only used in cofactor expansion; there are other ways to understand the determinant.  Here, cofactor expansion is really only used to understand the shape of the determinant, not calculate it precisely.  Therefore, the coefficients in the various polynomials that the person describes hide those $\pm 1$'s (without having to compute with them directly).

Comment: In the video, the person represented det(V)=g(x1)=ao+a1(x1)+......(an-1)(x1)^n. Then, he argued that x2.......xn are all roots of g(x1) so (an-1) is all that's left to be solved, then he said that (an-1) is the determinant of the minor.....the (-1)^(i+j) couldn't be hidden in the determinant of the minor right?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Argue that the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in $x_1$.  This is argued by considering cofactor expansion.  If one were to actually compute the the determinant using cofactor expansion, there would be a ton of $(-1)^{i+j}$'s here.  However, instead of doing the computation, the video performs a "thought experiment" to determine the shape of the determinant.  And concludes that it is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in $x_1$.

Interlude: The formula for cofactor expansion would be a *mess* to compute.  The goal of the video is figure out the determinant *without* going through the very long calculation of cofactor expansion.

Step 2: Determine that $x_1=x_2,\cdots,x_1=x_n$ are roots of the determinant.  This is done *without* actually computing the determinant, but, instead using the properties of the determinant.  If one had fully calculated the determinant in Step 1 and plugged in $x_1=x_2$, then the result would be zero, but since the video didn't actually compute the determinant, you must use *other* means to figure this out.  Since a polynomial of degree $n-1$ has $n-1$ roots (counted with multiplicities), this means that the determinant is of the form 
$$
g(x_2,\cdots,x_n)(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)\cdots (x_1-x_n).
$$
Here $g$ is some polynomial that does not depend on $x_1$.

Step 3: Figure out $g(x_2,\cdots,x_n)$.  Since $g(x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ is the coefficient of $x_1^{n-1}$, this can be calculated using cofactor expansion.  And can be seen to be another Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: Sir, I'm still so confused.....since the guy said that a0,a1,...an-1 are minors, the equation  g(x1)=ao+a1(x1)+......(an-1)(x1)^n actually uses cofactor expansion and then again where are the -1 terms??? sorry If i'm becoming annoying I am just so confused

Comment: $a_i$ isn't a number, it's some expression and could have a positive or negative sign.  The positives and negatives are absorbed into the unknown $a_i$'s.  Think of the following: $ax+b$ and $ax-c$ represent the same expression if $b=-c$.

Comment: but the guy said that ai is the determinant of the minor that's why at the end an-1 is the determinant of the smaller matrix

Comment: The person should have said that they are minors up to sign.  Try it yourself on a $3\times 3$ and you can see the coefficients in several ways.

Comment: Sir, please check the photo that I've attached above....this is what concerns me...the x1^3 on both methods are the same but the signs aren't....

Comment: The person on the video isn't worrying about signs.  The final answer in that case will be $\pm$ the actual determinant.

Comment: The ideas in the video are correct, but the person in the video is making mistakes.  It seems that you understand what's going on better than what is happening in the video.  Why don't you watch the video carefully and correct the mistakes that the person is making.

Comment: Oh....that makes sense now! All these time I kept thinking that the two values would be equal that's why I was so confused. So if I want the actual value of the determinant I can add the -1 term? Thanks a bunch kind Sir~